# How to detect click in radcombox source using an event not based on selectedIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

I have a `ComboBox` with 2 items. But on the loaded page I print an item not from the datasource which also has index 0.

How can I detect the click event on the first item (index 0) from the dropdownlist.

I need to distinguish the object A index 0 which is the displayed Item and the object B index 0 from the dropdownlist.
The Object A is displayed using text property of the combobox, so its assigned inndex is 0.

I can't use `SelectionChanged` because the event is based on `SelectedIndex`. here both have the same.

Here is some code, but not so helpfull (I tried using `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp`, but the event is not triggered on item) :

XAML

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="Combo" ItemsSource="{Binding ListeIndexationInit, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCodeIndexInitVentePV, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Combo_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
```

My code Behind xaml.cs

```
//Does not get the right index
private void RadComboBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RefOffreIndex value = Combo.SelectedValue as RefOffreIndex;
    if (value != null)
    {
        Combo.Text = value.ToString();
    }
    Combo.SelectedIndex = -1;
    var SelectionBoxItem = Combo.SelectionBoxItem;
    Combo.SelectedItem = value;
    var bindingExpression = Combo.GetBindingExpression(RadComboBox.SelectedItemProperty);
}
//Never triggered
private void Combo_SourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    Combo.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
//Event is too early
private void Combo_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var toto = 2;
}
```

Comment: is this asp.net or xaml? they are quite different from each other

Comment: also, show us some code

Comment: It is in xaml, I edited some code. Not sure it can help.

Comment: take a look at how an observable collection works in WPF. Ive used it in the past but not for a good few years at an old company.  Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197928/wpf-combobox-binding-to-observablecollection and google https://www.google.fr/search?q=observablecollection+combobox+wpf&oq=observablecollection+com&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0l2j0i22i30k1l2.150595.150898.0.152793.4.4.0.0.0.0.103.254.3j1.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.253.Q6xzBImaae4 This link should give you a set of results that will help

Comment: Thanks I'll check this, what I wan't to do is to invoke a method when the value changed, not the index.

Comment: This should probably do for you then